# Web Scrape ICISM application with heavy javascript

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, iframe

I'm trying to scrape job posting from this site:

https://external-maximus.icims.com/jobs/search?ss=1&hashed=-435771476&mobile=false&width=872&height=500&bga=true&needsRedirect=false&jan1offset=-300&jun1offset=-240

Specifically, when I inspect the page it looks like I need to go to redirect to the page referenced in the href of this tag:

```
<a id="icims_skipLink1" style="left: -9999px; position: absolute; top: -1px;" href=**"https://external-maximus.icims.com/jobs/search?ss=1&amp;hashed=-435771476&amp;mobile=false&amp;width=872&amp;height=500&amp;bga=true&amp;needsRedirect=false&amp;jan1offset=-300&amp;jun1offset=-240#icims_content_iframe"**>Skip Branding</a>
```

I'm using selenium and every single `find.element` doesn't work to find the link above.  I even downloaded the Selenium IDE to record the clicks to get to a job req instead of trying to alternatively go to the link above and selenium's `find.element` still can not find how to link to the job reqs.  I'm lost on what to do here.  Is it not possible to scrape this kind of site?